# How to use the authentication API to trigger password reset flow, python or curl

Tags: python, curl, https, python-requests, auth0

I'm trying to trigger a password reset flow with auth0 via the authentication api.

I keep getting this error:
`{"error":"email or username are required."}`

When following the instructions here:
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change#using-the-authentication-api

I'm trying to do it from jupyter notebook or from the terminal on my mac. Do I need to be doing something with the Allowed web origins setting in the dashboard?

The python request looks like this:

```
import requests


payload = "{\"client_id\": \"<MYCLIENTID>\",\"email\": \"<EMAIL>\",\"connection\": \"Username-Password-Authentication\"}"

headers = { 'content-type': "application/json" }

url = "https://<MYDOMAIN>/dbconnections/change_password"

print(requests.post(url, payload).text)
```

The curl request looks like this:

```
curl --request POST   --url 'https://<MYDOMAIN>/dbconnections/change_password'   --header 'content-type: application/json'   --data '{"client_id": "<MYCLIENTID>","email": "<MYEMAIL>","connection": "Username-Password-Authentication"}'
```

and returns the following error:

```
{"name":"BadRequestError","code":"invalid_parameter","description":"connection is disabled (client_id: <CLIENTID> - connection: Username-Password-Authentication)","statusCode":400}
```

All the <> values are replaced with real values...

Answer (score 1):

The `connection is disabled` errors usually indicate that the connection you are trying to use (`Username-Password-Authentication`), is not enabled on the given Application/Client.

To enable the connection for this Application, go to [Applications](https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications), select your Application and click on the Connections tab. Here you will see the list of all connections. Make sure the Database connection you are trying to use is enabled. It is advised to have only one enabled Database connection per Client/Application.